# Estimating flow direction using `terra::terrain()` without NA values at the border

Tags: r, hydrology, terra

Performing some rather simple watershed delination analysis I noticed `{terra}` offers a function to estimate at least the flow direction based on elevation input via `terrain(x, v = "flowdir")`.

Coming from ArcGIS originally, my first thought was to reproduce [the example given in their online help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/flow-direction.htm) in order to ensure consistency to prior behaviour.

```r
elev <- c(78, 72, 69, 71, 58, 49,
          74, 67, 56, 49, 46, 50,
          69, 53, 44, 37, 38, 48,
          64, 58, 55, 22, 31, 24,
          68, 61, 47, 21, 16, 19,
          74, 53, 34, 12, 11, 12) |> matrix(ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.29

dem <- rast(elev)

plot(dem)
text(dem)
```

[image]

```r
flowdir <- terrain(dem, v = "flowdir")

plot(flowdir)
text(flowdir)
```

[image]

Basically, the result seems quite identical to the one illustrated in `Flow_Dir` - only the cells adjacent to the border are `NA` when making use of `{terra}`. I understand this might be the formally correct way to show that there were not all 8 neighbouring cells available to properly determine the flow direction for the cells at the border but on the other hand, I was wondering if it would not be possible to estimate the direction nevertheless "as is", based on the data input.

Is there some parameter I am not aware of in order to estimate the flow direction using `terra::terrain(x, v = "flowdir")` also for the most outer cells?

Comment: As an example take the bottom right cell - value 12 - what flow direction would replace NA in this case?

Comment: Since 11 is the lowest neighbouring value, the direction would be "west" (=16) here. But yeah, you have the least information available when dealing with corner grid cells since there are only 3 out of 8 possible neighbours.

Comment: I'm wondering if you'd get a meaningful answer if you put a boundary of very large valued cells round the raster, then did the flowdir calc, then removed the result edge NAs...

Comment: Meaningful or not, this looks like a feasible way to enforce a result here nevertheless. Thanks for your input! Chaining `extend()` and `crop()` around `terrain()` looks promising: `terra::extend(dem, y = 1, fill = 9999) |> terra::terrain(v = "flowdir") |> terra::crop(y = dem)`. But I guess this implies there is not some sort of a native `force = TRUE` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having raised an issue at [rspatial/terra](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1180) because of (minor) inconsistencies in flow direction estimation at the basin outlet, this is what you now get making use of the development version of terra (v1.7-35+), making the extend/crop-workaround mentioned in the first answer no longer needed:

```r
elev <- c(78, 72, 69, 71, 58, 49,
          74, 67, 56, 49, 46, 50,
          69, 53, 44, 37, 38, 48,
          64, 58, 55, 22, 31, 24,
          68, 61, 47, 21, 16, 19,
          74, 53, 34, 12, 11, 12) |> matrix(ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.35

dem <- rast(elev)

flowdir <- terrain(dem, v = "flowdir")

plot(flowdir)
text(flowdir)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just to make use of the information provided in the comments by @Spacedman:

Chaining `extend()` and `crop()` around `terrain()` seems to do the trick in general to keep the information along the boundaries, but I'll wait some more time before accepting this answer in case someone shows up with an even more elegant idea:

```r
elev <- c(78, 72, 69, 71, 58, 49,
          74, 67, 56, 49, 46, 50,
          69, 53, 44, 37, 38, 48,
          64, 58, 55, 22, 31, 24,
          68, 61, 47, 21, 16, 19,
          74, 53, 34, 12, 11, 12) |> matrix(ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.29

dem <- rast(elev)

flowdir <- extend(dem, y = 1, fill = 9999) |> 
  terrain(v = "flowdir") |> 
  crop(y = dem)

plot(flowdir)
text(flowdir)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>